# Can't chroot a user

Tags: ssh, chroot, sftp

My ssh-server has been working like a charm for 4 years now, so I just want to add a user + chroot him to a specific folder.

```
> useradd -m -c /home/thomas -s /bin/sh thomas
> passwd thomas
> chmod 755 /home/thomas
> chown root: /home/thomas
> service ssh restart
```

When I do this, I **can** connect through `ssh` and my `sftp` connexion works. The problem is that I want to chroot to a specific folder.

```
> vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Add at the end of the file:

```
Match user thomas
    ChrootDirectory /home/%u
```

When I only add this, this shouldn't change something right? The configuration should be the same and I still should be able to connect or use sftp... so I restart with `service ssh restart` and I cant connect with sftp anymore.

Just in case:

```
root@xx:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# /usr/sbin/sshd -v
sshd: illegal option -- v
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u6, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
usage: sshd [-46DdeiqTt] [-b bits] [-C connection_spec] [-c host_cert_file]
            [-f config_file] [-g login_grace_time] [-h host_key_file]
            [-k key_gen_time] [-o option] [-p port] [-u len]
root@xx:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled#
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you read the `sshd_config` manual about creating some necessary `/dev` files in the chroot directory?

Comment: No.. what is it about? May I ask you a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sshd_config` manual states that

> The `ChrootDirectory` must contain the necessary files and
>                directories to support the user's session.  For an interactive
>                session this requires at least a shell, typically `sh(1)`, and
>                basic `/dev` nodes such as `null(4)`, `zero(4)`, `stdin(4)`, `stdout(4)`,
>                `stderr(4)`, and `tty(4)` devices.  For file transfer sessions using
>                SFTP no additional configuration of the environment is necessary
>                if the in-process sftp-server is used, though sessions which use
>                logging may require `/dev/log` inside the chroot directory on some
>                operating systems (see `sftp-server(8)` for details).

You should create the `dev` directory and then copy the `/dev/MAKEDEV` script there. Using the script, create the needed device files.

For interactive users, you need to install the necessary binaries and associated libraries in the chroot too.

The reference to "the in-process sftp-server" means `ForceCommand internal-sftp` should be used in your `Match` block.

Note: the excerpt is from OpenSSH 7.5 since I don't have access to any older SSH implementation.

Comment: MAKEDEV should be launched as root or as the user itself (= thomas in my case)?

Comment: @OlivierPons As `root`.

Comment: From where? /home/thomas and inside (/home/thomas/dev/): both didn't create null, zero, stdin and stdout etc nodes.

Comment: I can connect through ssh, it's ch-rooted, but I cant connect through sftp (which is my primary goal). Any suggestion?

Comment: Update the question with the output form `sftp -vvv ...`. It's hard to debug blindfolded.

Comment: @OlivierPons You also need to add `ForceCommand internal-sftp` to the statements after the `Match`...

Comment: That was it! I dont know why this command isn't in all the examples I've found on the Web... Thank you very much indeed!